# Basic IOS OOP - structure and implementation

Tags: objective-c, ios, oop

I am creating a basic guessing game in iOS for my kids, and I think there are some fundamental gaps in my understanding of how I should be creating and releasing objects throughout the lifecycle of the app. I have been reading up on retain and release cycles but I think my issue is more to do with the fundamental architecture of the app and how I may be poorly trying to instantiate and then kill a few key objects of the app.

The problem centers around two specific classes.

I have a game class, which I have designed to hold all the information that the game requires to run. When it is init-ed, it holds all instance variables that point to arrays that hold strings such as the various clues, etc. It's basically a container for all the data that the game requires.

I have a game view controller, that creates and an instance of the game class and queries it so as to present on screen the various elements contained with the game object.

This works perfectly the fine. When the user starts a new game, a new instance of the game class is allocated and init-ed and away they go.

The issue comes in when I come to generate a new game. This happens a number of ways. Either The user finishes the game and starts another one or the user quits the current game and then starts a new one.

In my thinking, I would just release the game object and alloc and init a new one. However, I notice running on the device and looking through the profiler, that the game object isn't released at all.It's still, there and each instantiation of the game creates a new game object with the old one still sitting there with no pointers to it.

Fiddling around with the code, I noticed that I did not implement a dealloc method in the Game class...but when I try to do that, the app crashes, I suspect because I am trying to release a previously released object.

Ideally what I am trying to do is get rid of the old Game object, or replace the old one (overwrite) with a new one each time a new game is started.

However, is this approach wrong?  Should I be doing it a completely different way? Such as only ever creating a single instance of the game class and rewriting a method inside that class so as to generate a new set of clues, etc everytime a new game starts and the GameViewController tells it to?

Is there a 'best practice' way to do this?

So you've got an idea of what I am doing, code is below for the GameViewController, where an instance of the Game class is created:

```
#import "GameViewController.h"

@implementation GameViewController

@synthesize game =  _game;


-(void)startNewGameOfLevel:(NSInteger)level
    {
        if(!_game)
        {
            Game *g = [[Game alloc]initGamewithLevel:level]; 
            [self setGame:g];
            [g release]; g = nil;
        }

        [self set_currentlevel:[_game _currentLevel]];

        // set up popover to show the rounds goal letter
        [self setUpPopOver];

    }

-(void)quitTheCurrentGameAndStartNewGame
{
    [_game release]; _game = nil;
    [self clearGamePlayingField];
     animationStepIndex =  0;
    [self startNewGameOfLevel: _currentlevel];
}
```

Game class (abridged) with the designated initializer of the Game class:

```
    #import "Game.h"


    @implementation Game

    @synthesize arrayOfLowerCaseLetters = _arrayOfLowerCaseLetters;
    @synthesize arrayOfPhrases=  _arrayOfPhrases;

    @synthesize goalLetter = _goalLetter;
    @synthesize goalPhrase = _goalPhrase;
    @synthesize gameLetterPool = _gameLetterPool;

    @synthesize _indexForGoalLetter, _numberOfLevelsInGame, _currentLevel, _numberOfWhackHoles, _numberOfLettersInGameLetterPool;

    -(id)initGamewithLevel:(NSInteger)level
    {
        [super init];

        //create an array of lower case letters. These will
        //contain the full alphabet of all possible letters

        NSArray *arrayOfLCLetters = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"c", @"d",@"e", @"f", @"g", @"h", @"i", @"j", @"k", @"l", @"m", @"n", @"o", @"p", @"qu", @"r", @"s", @"t", @"u", @"v", @"w", @"x",@"y", @"z",@"ch", @"sh", @"th", nil];
        [self setArrayOfLowerCaseLetters: arrayOfLCLetters];
        [arrayOfLCLetters release];arrayOfLCLetters = nil;

        //create an array of phrases.
        // These must correspond with each of the letters. e.g. a = apple.

        NSArray *phrases= [[NSArray alloc ] initWithObjects:
                           @"apple",
                           @"butterfly",
                           @"cat",
                           @"dog",
                           @"egg",
                           @"frog",
                           @"ghost",
                           @"horse",
                           @"igloo",
                           @"jam",
                           @"kite",
                           @"leaf",
                           @"moon",
                           @"nut",
                           @"orange",
                           @"pig",
                           @"queen",
                           @"rabbit",
                           @"snake",
                           @"tree",
                           @"umbrella",
                           @"van",
                           @"water",
                           @"x-ray",
                           @"yak",
                           @"Zebra",
                           @"chair",
                           @"shoes",
                           @"thumb",

                           nil];
        [self setArrayOfPhrases:phrases];
        [phrases release]; phrases = nil;


        //choose a random number to be the index reference for
        // each goal letter and goal phrase.
        [self set_indexForGoalLetter:(arc4random()%[_arrayOfLowerCaseLetters count])];
        NSLog(@"index for goal letter is:, %i", _indexForGoalLetter);

        //set Goal letter and goal phrase
        [self setGoalLetter: [_arrayOfLowerCaseLetters objectAtIndex: _indexForGoalLetter]];
        [self setGoalPhrase: [_arrayOfPhrases objectAtIndex:_indexForGoalLetter ]];

        //set current level
        [self set_currentLevel: level];
        //[self set_currentLevel: 2];


        //set number of whackholes by level
        [self set_numberOfWhackHoles: [self numberOfWhackHolesByLevel:_currentLevel]];

        //generate size of Letter pool by level
        [self set_numberOfLettersInGameLetterPool:[self numberOfLettersInLetterPoolbyLevel:_currentLevel]];

        ////////////////////////////
        ///  Game letter pool
        ///////////////////////////

        //set up array ton hold the pool of letters
        NSMutableArray *gp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:_numberOfLettersInGameLetterPool];
        [self setGameLetterPool: gp];
        [gp release];gp = nil;

        //add the goal letter to this pool
        [_gameLetterPool addObject:_goalLetter];

        int i = 1;

        while (i < _numberOfLettersInGameLetterPool) {
            NSString *letter = [_arrayOfLowerCaseLetters objectAtIndex:(arc4random()%[_arrayOfLowerCaseLetters count])];
            if ([_gameLetterPool containsObject:letter] == false)
            {
                [_gameLetterPool addObject:letter];
                i++;
            }

        }

        NSLog(@"********** Game created  ***************");
        NSLog(@"pool of letters is: %@", [_gameLetterPool description]);
        NSLog(@"****************************************");
        NSLog(@"current goal letter is: %@", _goalLetter);
            NSLog(@"****************************************");
        NSLog(@"current goal phrase is: %@", _goalPhrase);
            NSLog(@"****************************************");

        return self;
    }

-(void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
    [_arrayOfLowerCaseLetters release]; _arrayOfLowerCaseLetters = nil;
    [_arrayOfPhrases release]; _arrayOfPhrases = nil;
    [_goalLetter release];_goalLetter = nil;
    [_goalPhrase release]; _goalPhrase = nil;
    [_gameLetterPool release];_gameLetterPool = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The number one problem is that `[super dealloc]` must be the absolute last thing you do in `-dealloc`.  This is because it is the `dealloc` method in NSObject that actually frees the memory, so by the time you get back to it, your instance variable pointers may already be garbage.

Other issues:

In init, do `self = [super init];`  The super object is allowed to return a different self pointer on init.

`startNewGameOfLevel:` and `quitTheCurrentGameAndStartNewGame` should use the property, not the bare instance variable.

```
-(void)startNewGameOfLevel:(NSInteger)level
    {
        if(![self game])
        {
            Game *g = [[Game alloc]initGamewithLevel:level]; 
            [self setGame:g];
            [g release]; g = nil;// g = nil, not necessary when it's about to go out of scope
        }

        [self set_currentlevel:[[self game] _currentLevel]]; // don't use _ to start methods - Apple reserves this convention

        // set up popover to show the rounds goal letter
        [self setUpPopOver];

    }

-(void)quitTheCurrentGameAndStartNewGame
{
    [self setGame: nil];
    [self clearGamePlayingField];
     animationStepIndex =  0;
    [self startNewGameOfLevel: _currentlevel];
}
```

There are probably other issues in the body of your code - make sure you build with static analysis enables - it will catch many of them.